# After upgrading to thunderbird 60 my dictionaries were disabled and I can't install them again

Tags: thunderbird, dictionary

After upgrading to thunderbird 60 I discovered that my non-english dictionaries were silently disabled and I can't install them again because thunderbird complains "dictionary can not be installed because it is not compatible with Thunderbird 60..."

Answer (score 0):

It is a [known issue](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1456988). One work around is to temporarily disable the compatibility check. This is not dangerous at all for dictionaries (see discussion in the [TB's bug tracker](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1456988)).

To disable the check you have to [start TB's config editor](https://support.mozilla.org/el/kb/config-editor), then type `extensions.strictCompatibility` and double click the `True` to switch it to `false`. Don't forget to re-set it to `True` after installing the dictionary.

Comment: > It is a known issue.

But [a patch was added to version 60 ](https://bugzilla.mozilla.org/show_bug.cgi?id=1456988#c45) so it should be working .